# Make a query with JSON

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I have JSON data gets Vedios data of youtube list. And the following link display structure of my JSON.

```
<a href="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=UUbW18JZRgko_mOGm5er8Yzg&key=AIzaSyDGm1uzuqPPUGzG-qN7u6gTaS8ApXBJYvw"> 
Click me to get all list videos ID ...
</a>
```

[And here is the channel with its ID](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6ZMfKr4BOw&list=UUbW18JZRgko_mOGm5er8Yzg&index=1)

After analyses of my JASON, I have JSON array named "items" (row 9).
Now all I need to get specific information from all units included with this array "items".

All I need to make a query using JavaScript or c# to return JSON with this specific data

1. title
2. description
3. thumbnails - standard
4. videoId

Comment: what have you tried? Have you tried an ajax request to the page?

Comment: AJAX as keyword should be enough to find a solution in 5, 4, 3,.. 2. ...1

Comment: please @webdeb  give me an example

Comment: What's wrong with the example from Timur Gilauri?

Comment: Gilauri's example not answer what I'm asking about. it's just make HTTP request. My question is about how to select specific keys from JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution for my problem. Not very professional but good for now.

I used Jquery selectors to extract data from my JSON object as following.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

        var jsonLink = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&playlistId=PL0zTBP9-UnPaIurxKLr3rfPZwHrFl2mEq&key=AIzaSyDGm1uzuqPPUGzG-qN7u6gTaS8ApXBJYvw&maxResults=50";

        $.getJSON(jsonLink).done(function (data) {
            var items = [];

            $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
                items.push("<li>" + item.snippet.title + "</li>");

                if (i === 5) {
                    return false;
                }
            });

            $("<ul/>", {
                "class": "my-new-list",
                html: items.join("")
            }).appendTo("body");

        });


    });
```

Comment: You should not be answering your own question then posing a new question with your answer. It is disrespectful to those using their time to help you and does not improve the community. Edit your original question, delete it, or open a new question.